# How can i read "Multiple lines Words" from .txt file and store them in an array using java?

Tags: java

I can't read multiple word in separete lines from .txt file using java. I only can read one line from it. I need to store each word in .txt file into a array of strings. here is my code can please someone help me how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Post your code here, not as an image. Edit, paste, select the code, press ctrl-k.

Comment: You should post your code, in your IMG you are already reading all the lines in the file, you just need to stored in words[cont++] = read; also to print "words" you need to used a for